# Grafana CloudWatch query to reference SERVICE_QUOTA

Tags: grafana, amazon-cloudwatch

According to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/CloudWatch-Quotas-Visualize-Alarms.html, we can perform CloudWatch math expression like this on the AWS CloudWatch console `m1/SERVICE_QUOTA(m1)*100` where `m1` is a CloudWatch metric.

Is there any way we can do the same thing in the Grafana's CloudWatch query where we reference `SERVICE_QUOTA()` in the Grafana CloudWatch query Expression field?

[Sample screenshot of Grafana CloudWatch query expression](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUyTf.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CloudWatch math in Grafana. See doc: https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/datasources/aws-cloudwatch/#metric-math-expressions

You can find also ready dashboard for this use case: https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/12979

Comment: I think this is what I need. Thanks.

Comment: I don't see the `expression` field in a newer version of grafana + the AWS Cloudwatch plugin.
They've reformatted the UI for it, and there's no longer an AWS specific `expression` field in there.
There are grafana math expressions you can add, but these are pure math on the retrieved value and do not let you call the `SERVICE_QUOTA()` API.

I'm on grafana 8.5.25